# Pass string into JSON format and its automatically encoded

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to pass a json string to a Javascript function, and JSON generated dynamically. but after pass the JSON parameter in function it double quotes encode with "e;.
I am using C# MVC 4.0
here is my code :-

```
string strAllImages = "[";

foreach (var images in Model.PostsImageList)
{    
     if (strAllImages.Trim() != "[")
     {
         strAllImages = strAllImages + ",";
     }
     strAllImages = strAllImages + "'~/postImages/" + images.Image_Post_URL + "'";            

}   

strAllImages = strAllImages + "]";

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){ // on document load

    $("#thumbsliderdiv").imageSlider({ //initialize slider
        'thumbs': @strAllImages, 
        'auto_scroll':true,
        'auto_scroll_speed':4500,
        'stop_after': 2, //stop after x cycles? Set to 0 to disable.
        'canvas_width':700,
        'canvas_height':500 // <-- No comma after last option
        })
});

</script>
```

Comment: JSON requires double-quotes. You should use the .NET JSON library to encode your array instead of doing it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's missing in your code to make it immediatly work is :

```
'thumbs': @Html.Raw(strAllImages)
```

But it will more clean if you use [JSON.net](https://json.codeplex.com/). E.g :

```
string [] strAllImagesAsArray = Model.PostsImageList.Select(i =>  "'~/postImages/" + i.Image_Post_URL + "'").ToArray() ;
```

And in you javascript :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){ // on document load

    $("#thumbsliderdiv").imageSlider({ //initialize slider
        'thumbs': @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(strAllImagesAsArray)),
        'auto_scroll':true,
        'auto_scroll_speed':4500,
        'stop_after': 2, //stop after x cycles? Set to 0 to disable.
        'canvas_width':700,
        'canvas_height':500 // <-- No comma after last option
        })
});

</script>
```